# Cross-compiling and running hello world for ARM Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to run hello world program on ARM computer with Linux (Debian Wheezy). The libc version on it is 2.13, while my own computer has 2.15 (Ubuntu Precise).
I installed arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc on my computer and compiled the application with static linkage.

All my attempts to run compiled binary result in "cannot execute binary file" message. However, QEMU on my own computer (qemu-arm-static) runs the application succesfully.

I thought that it should be enough to link my app statically. The permissions are 755. What am I missing here?

UPD: I tried to install Arch Linux on that ARM. In that distribution my compiled binaries crash with segfault instead of bash error message. Does stock cross compiler in Ubuntu distribution ever work? :-/

Thanks!

Comment: did you check the permissions of the binary on target, to start with?

Comment: Yes, the permissions are 644.

Comment: ok, how you're trying to run it? hope using `./<binary_name>`, right?

Comment: @sourav I ssh into ARM computer and say `./hello-static`

Comment: Have you tried to use an embedded Linux distro like Buildroot or Yocto? This would take more time to create rootfs, but then you'll have everything cross-compiled with one toolchain, so that such errors won't occur.

Comment: Is this armel or armhf Wheezy?

Comment: @unixsmurf This is armel.

Comment: @yegorich I'm pretty sure Buildroot will work, but I'd like to find out the cause of this error, if possible.

Comment: What does ldd on the target platform tell you?

Comment: Which permissions do you mean? 755 (in question) or 644 (in comments)?

Comment: @ioan 755. 644 is mistake.

Comment: @unixsmurf ldd says it's not dynamically linked executable.

Comment: What does "file hello-static" say?

Comment: @RichardPennington
`hello-static: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0x58f377eaa0e3739830140c6203427be3211404f8, not stripped`

Comment: Could it be I've compiled it for wrong ARM architecture? How can I check it? My target board is OLinuxino i.MX-233.